# vertical screen tearing when scrolling

Tags: graphics, ati, multiple-monitors, mate, tearing

I have a Radeon X800 XL GPU I have been using for a while. Today I gave my 24" monitor to a friend, and set up 2, 22" monitors rotated. Things seemed to be working well, but I just noticed there is vertical screen tearing, when I scroll on web-pages. what might I do to get rid of the tearing?

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 mate edition.

I looked in the bios for the option to increase the amount of video buffer memory but there was no such option.

Comment: did you resolve the issue in the end? Maybe it connected to refresh rate?